# Problem with some LWJGL classes on import (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I downloaded the release build without modifying (https://www.lwjgl.org/customize)
I put all the classes in Eclipse. Some classes are not recognized

[image: Errors]

The codes that do not need these classes in error, work normally. As in https://www.lwjgl.org/guide

[image: Java build path]

All the classes I put:

```
joml-1.10.1.jar  
joml-1.10.1-javadoc.jar  
joml-1.10.1-sources.jar  
lwjgl.jar  
lwjgl-assimp.jar  
lwjgl-assimp-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-assimp-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-assimp-sources.jar  
lwjgl-bgfx.jar  
lwjgl-bgfx-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-bgfx-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-bgfx-sources.jar  
lwjgl-cuda.jar    
lwjgl-cuda-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-cuda-sources.jar  
lwjgl-egl.jar  
lwjgl-egl-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-egl-sources.jar  
lwjgl-glfw.jar  
lwjgl-glfw-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-glfw-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-glfw-sources.jar  
lwjgl-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-jawt.jar  
lwjgl-jawt-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-jawt-sources.jar  
lwjgl-jemalloc.jar  
lwjgl-jemalloc-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-jemalloc-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-jemalloc-sources.jar  
lwjgl-libdivide.jar  
lwjgl-libdivide-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-libdivide-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-libdivide-sources.jar  
lwjgl-llvm.jar  
lwjgl-llvm-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-llvm-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-llvm-sources.jar  
lwjgl-lmdb.jar  
lwjgl-lmdb-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-lmdb-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-lmdb-sources.jar  
lwjgl-lz4.jar  
lwjgl-lz4-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-lz4-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-lz4-sources.jar  
lwjgl-meow.jar  
lwjgl-meow-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-meow-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-meow-sources.jar  
lwjgl-nanovg.jar  
lwjgl-nanovg-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-nanovg-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-nanovg-sources.jar  
lwjgl-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-nfd.jar  
lwjgl-nfd-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-nfd-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-nfd-sources.jar  
lwjgl-nuklear.jar  
lwjgl-nuklear-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-nuklear-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-nuklear-sources.jar  
lwjgl-odbc.jar  
lwjgl-odbc-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-odbc-sources.jar  
lwjgl-openal.jar  
lwjgl-openal-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-openal-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-openal-sources.jar  
lwjgl-opencl.jar  
lwjgl-opencl-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-opencl-sources.jar  
lwjgl-opengl.jar  
lwjgl-opengles.jar  
lwjgl-opengles-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-opengles-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-opengles-sources.jar  
lwjgl-opengl-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-opengl-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-opengl-sources.jar  
lwjgl-openvr.jar  
lwjgl-openvr-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-openvr-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-openvr-sources.jar  
lwjgl-opus.jar  
lwjgl-opus-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-opus-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-opus-sources.jar  
lwjgl-ovr.jar  
lwjgl-ovr-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-ovr-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-ovr-sources.jar  
lwjgl-par.jar  
lwjgl-par-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-par-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-par-sources.jar  
lwjgl-remotery.jar  
lwjgl-remotery-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-remotery-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-remotery-sources.jar  
lwjgl-rpmalloc.jar  
lwjgl-rpmalloc-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-rpmalloc-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-rpmalloc-sources.jar  
lwjgl-shaderc.jar  
lwjgl-shaderc-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-shaderc-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-shaderc-sources.jar  
lwjgl-sources.jar  
lwjgl-sse.jar  
lwjgl-sse-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-sse-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-sse-sources.jar  
lwjgl-stb.jar  
lwjgl-stb-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-stb-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-stb-sources.jar  
lwjgl-tinyexr.jar  
lwjgl-tinyexr-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-tinyexr-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-tinyexr-sources.jar  
lwjgl-tinyfd.jar  
lwjgl-tinyfd-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-tinyfd-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-tinyfd-sources.jar  
lwjgl-tootle.jar  
lwjgl-tootle-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-tootle-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-tootle-sources.jar  
lwjgl-vma.jar  
lwjgl-vma-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-vma-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-vma-sources.jar  
lwjgl-vulkan.jar  
lwjgl-vulkan-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-vulkan-sources.jar  
lwjgl-xxhash.jar  
lwjgl-xxhash-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-xxhash-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-xxhash-sources.jar  
lwjgl-yoga.jar  
lwjgl-yoga-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-yoga-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-yoga-sources.jar  
lwjgl-zstd.jar  
lwjgl-zstd-javadoc.jar  
lwjgl-zstd-natives-windows.jar  
lwjgl-zstd-sources.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compile LWJGL **2** code here. All the imports that it cannot find pertain to the verison **2** of LWJGL. The current version that you can get from the mentioned lwjgl site is **3** and version **3** is *incompatible* with version **2**.

Either explicitly download LWJGL **2** from e.g. http://legacy.lwjgl.org/ or rewrite your code to work with LWJGL **3**.

If you go the LWJGL **2** route, though, please note that it hasn't been actively maintained anymore for more than 6 years now.